# How to get media entity field value in twig?

Tags: theming, 8

Sometimes it is necessary to get the actual value of a field (not the formatted/rendered one), e.g. to check a boolean for `true` or `false`.

If I want to get a field value of a *node* or *paragraph* inside twig templates (*node.html.twig* / *paragraph.html.twig*) I can use `node.field_my_boolean.value` respectively `paragraph.field_my_boolean.value`.

How do I accomplish this in a *media* twig template? I've already tried `media.field_my_boolean.value` but it does not work.

Comment: try `{{ content.field_my_boolean }}` and you want the raw value without the HTML markup `{{ content.field_my_boolean.0 }}`

Comment: Both output the rendered value and not the actuall true/false. I can not use this because it is translated (e.g. "wahr"/"falsch" in German).

Comment: When you do `{{ content.field_my_boolean.0 }}` is it showing `wahr/flasch` or `1/0` ?

Comment: It depends on the display format setting. If I set the formatter to `1/0` I get `1` or `0`. If I set it to ``wahr/falsch` I get `wahr` or `falsch`. That's what I mean by "rendered value".

Comment: I have adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, the Media module does not pass its object in the variables like Paragraphs and Node does. This is why `media.field_my_boolean.value` does nothing.

You can correct this in your theme by implementing `theme_preprocess_media`, which adds the media object to the variables:

```
/**
 * Prepares variables for media templates.
 *
 * Default template: media.html.twig.
 *
 * @param array $variables
 *   An associative array containing:
 *   - media: An individual media for display.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_media(&$variables) {
  $variables['media'] = $variables['elements']['#media'];
}
```

You can then access `media.` in your twig template and any connected fields on it just like Paragraph or Node.

Comment: You seem to be right. Actually `function mytheme_preprocess_media(&$variables) {$variables['media'] = $variables['elements']['#media']}` should be enough because your themes preprocess function is just adding variables. No need to copy the whole function from media module.

Comment: Gotcha - for some reason I had to use the whole function, could be an earlier build.

Comment: OK, I'm referring to Drupal 8.3.0 and Media Entity 8.x-1.6. Just update your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can with `{{ content.field_my_boolean }}` and if you want the raw value without the HTML markup use `content.field_my_boolean.0`

> Both output the rendered value and not the actuall true/false. I can
>   not use this because it is translated (e.g. "wahr"/"falsch" in
>   German).

Then use the `|t` function and do this

```
{% if content.field_my_boolean.0 == 'Wahr'|t %}
    // do something
{% elseif content.field_my_boolean.0 == 'Falsch'|t %}
    // do something
{% endif %}
```